# how can i compile xcode 4.5 code to xcode 4.3?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, xcode4.3, xcode4.5

I am making a project based xcode 4.5, but I have a problem, which is that project has to support iOS 4.0 now. So I found a mac installed on Xcode 4.3.

But here's problem start. My code doesn't work on xcode 4.3, because my code has iOS 6 code like

```
-(NSInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations
```

I don't want to use `respondsToSelector` because if I use that method, I have to do same work so many times. So I want to use a macro that check xcode version or iOS SDK check? I think if I found that macro, I can determine what code has to compile or not. How can I make that macro?

Comment: Upvoted for beautiful prose.

Comment: Sorry, I ruined it for better readability. :)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the .h files of apple, they are full of that macros.
For example MkMapView.h

```
#if (__IPHONE_5_0 <= __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED)
```

or this

```
- (void)addOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay NS_AVAILABLE(NA, 4_0);
```

You find more in file

> /usr/include/Availability.h

there is detailed documentation, too